# Solutions to system of equations $x_{i-1}=n^{x_{i}}$ for $i=1,2,...,m$.

Tags: number-theory

Consider the system of equations
$x_{i-1}=n^{x_{i}}$, for a given $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0,1\}$, with real variables $x_{i}$ and $i=1,2,...,m$.  If $x_{0}$ and $x_{m}$ are rational, is there a nonrational $x_{i}$?

Comment: I think not. If $x_1$ is irrational, then $x_0 = n^{x_1}$ is transcendental by the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem).

Comment: I forgot to mention that the case m=1 is trivial and m=2 has already been answered in a previous question.  You just answered the case m=2.

Comment: Well, the above Gelfond-Schneider argument combined with induction gives the general case. It reduces $x_0,x_m$ both rational to $x_1,x_m$ both rational. In fact Gelfond-Schneider says $x_k$ rational implies $x_{k+1}$ rational, as far as I can see.

Comment: Doesn't Gelfond-Schneider handle every case directly? Just apply it to the smallest non-rational $x_i$ (if there are none, you're done).

Comment: *earliest, not smallest

Comment: @Tesla The first comment by preferred_anon should refer only to algebraic irrationals.  If $x_1$ is trascendental, $x_0$ can still be rational.

Comment: Guess I overlooked the hypothesis.